# EXSLT date:format-date template without document() XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, date, document, msxml, exslt

I'm using [date:format-date template EXSLT file](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html) I'm using XSLT 1.0 and MSXML3.0  as the processor.

My date:format-date template EXSLT file's declaration is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  extension-element-prefixes="msxsl date str">
   ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I cannot use document() function due to the 3rd party restrictions. So I have changed the months and days (similarly) **from XML snippet:**

```
<date:months>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Jan">January</date:month>
  <date:month length="28" abbr="Feb">February</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Mar">March</date:month>
  <date:month length="30" abbr="Apr">April</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="May">May</date:month>
  <date:month length="30" abbr="Jun">June</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Jul">July</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Aug">August</date:month>
  <date:month length="30" abbr="Sep">September</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Oct">October</date:month>
  <date:month length="30" abbr="Nov">November</date:month>
  <date:month length="31" abbr="Dec">December</date:month>
</date:months>
```

**to the variable:**

```
 <xsl:variable name="months">
   <month length="31" abbr="Jan">January</month>
   <month length="28" abbr="Feb">February</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="Mar">March</month>
   <month length="30" abbr="Apr">April</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="May">May</month>
   <month length="30" abbr="Jun">June</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="Jul">July</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="Aug">August</month>
   <month length="30" abbr="Sep">September</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="Oct">October</month>
   <month length="30" abbr="Nov">November</month>
   <month length="31" abbr="Dec">December</month>
</xsl:variable>
```

And correspondingly, I've changed the code that originally uses document() function **from:**
[from month processing bit of EXSLT stylesheet]

```
<xsl:variable name="month-node" select="document('')/*/date:months/date:month[number($month)]" />
```

**to use MSXML3.0 node-set function**:

```
<xsl:variable name="month-node" select="msxsl:node-set($months)/month[number($month)]" />
```

So I assumed that this would work.

According to the EXLT instructions "The format pattern string is interpreted as described for the JDK 1.1 [SimpleDateFormat class.](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se-eol.html)" [I used current version].

I'm specifing the month in accordance to [SimpleDateFormat class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as 'dd MMMMM yyyy' so that the month will be the full month's name, for example January. But it doesn't work :( I've looked in EXSLT stylesheet and it has got the logic to do that. Also there is logic to display the name of the week for a day using 'E' pattern, which doesn't work for me. Maybe changing from using document() to variables broke it.

Would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

**EXAMPLES**

```
<xsl:call-template name="date:format-date">
    <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="'2010-07-01'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'dd MMMMM yyyy'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

As I understand from [SimpleDateFormat class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs this should result in **01 July 2010** and what I get is **01 07 2010**

```
<xsl:call-template name="date:format-date">
    <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="'2010-07-01'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'EEE, dd MMMMM yyyy'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

This should result in **Mon, 01 July 2010** and what I get is **, 01 07 2010**

Answer (score 0):

When you use `msxml:node-set` on a rootless fragment of XML (like your list of months), the function automatically creates a root to contain the fragment.

So in your case your path from the node set is wrong:

```
msxsl:node-set($months)/month[number($month)]
```

This is wrong because `/month` is not the root of `$months`. You can fix it easily by skipping the artificial root and going to month directly:

```
msxsl:node-set($months)//month[number($month)]
```

Note the `//` operator instead of the `/` operator.

**EDIT**

Upon testing I see that I'm wrong. In fact, the original snippet that you are using works fine for me. The `//` operator is unnecessary. Are you sure your `$month` variable is being set correctly?

Comment: @Welbog: I think it is. I've edited the structure of $months so that I can use it without document(). I do get results, but not exactly formated in the correct way. I've added examples in the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the EXSLT page you reference ([date:format-date template EXSLT file](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html)):

> There are currently no XSLT processors
>   that we know of that support
>   date:format-date natively.

What implementation are you using?  It doesn't seem to be supported natively in MSXML.